# How to fetch the default payment method type from a list of payment methods

Tags: ruby, braintree

I customized the payment form using the hosted fields, and saved few payment methods for a customer which worked fine.

I added the last payment method as default using,

```
:options => {
              :make_default => true
            }
```

How can I fetch the particular payment method from a list of payment methods? The payment method to which default is assigned does not have any default attribute.

Here is my payment method:

```
#<Braintree::CreditCard token: "95mp9m", billing_address: #<Braintree::Address:0x000000089f83e8 @gateway=#<Braintree::Gateway:0x0000000866cf30 @config=#<Braintree::Configuration:0x0000000866d160 @endpoint=nil, @environment=:sandbox, @public_key="spqbkwzjcc54x5dc", @private_key="[FILTERED]">>, @id="sg", @customer_id="29261218", @first_name=nil, @last_name=nil, @company=nil, @street_address="123 Abc Way", @extended_address=nil, @locality=nil, @region=nil, @postal_code=nil, @country_code_alpha2=nil, @country_code_alpha3=nil, @country_code_numeric=nil, @country_name=nil, @created_at=2016-03-17 15:59:33 UTC, @updated_at=2016-03-17 15:59:33 UTC>, bin: "401288", card_type: "Visa", cardholder_name: nil, created_at: 2016-03-17 15:59:34 UTC, customer_id: "29261218", expiration_month: "12", expiration_year: "2020", last_4: "1881", updated_at: 2016-03-17 15:59:34 UTC, prepaid: "No", payroll: "Unknown", commercial: "Unknown", debit: "Unknown", durbin_regulated: "Unknown", healthcare: "Unknown", country_of_issuance: "", issuing_bank: "Unknown", image_url: "https://assets.braintreegateway.com/payment_method_logo/visa.png?environment=sandbox">
```

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work for Braintree.</sub>

`default?` is a method, not a field, on PaymentMethod objects so inspecting will not show its default status. To solve your problem, iterate over the list of PaymentMethods until you find a default.

```
customer = Braintree::Customer.find("customer_id")

default_payment_method = customer.payment_methods.find do |pm|
  pm.default?
end
```

If you have any further questions, feel free to reach out to [Braintree support](https://support.braintreepayments.com).